# PHP/MySQL search engine, I cannot find the images folder path

Tags: php, mysql, path

I am a PHP newbie and I am developing a ecommerce website as a project. I have made a PHP/MySQL search engine for the website. The search engine works fine...But the issue is that when the result display...It cannot find the path of the images located in the folders... How can I find the images path to display the images?

```
Here the site structure:

    Main folder: egoshop
    women-fashion folder
    index.php
    images
      -bag.jpg
      -glass.jpg
    -------------------------------
    men-fashion folder
      -index.php
    images
      -tie.jpg
      -shoes.jpg
    -----------------
    includes folder
    -------------------
    index.php
```

### search.php

```
Here is my search form
<form method="get" action="">   
  <span class="field"><input type="text" name="recherche" id="recherche" placeholder="Entrer exemple : Basket, docside" /></span><span class="btn"><input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Recherche" /></span>
```

```
index.php

<?php
if (isset($_GET['go'])) {

try {

 $sql = "SELECT products.productID,productNAME,productDESC,productPRICE,productIMG FROM products WHERE productNAME LIKE :recherche";

 $s= $pdo->prepare($sql);

 $s->bindValue(':recherche', '%' . $_GET['recherche'] .'%'); 

 $s->execute();

 $s->bindColumn('productID', $product_id);

 $s->bindColumn('productNAME', $pname);

 $s->bindColumn('productDESC', $pdesc);

 $s->bindColumn('productPRICE', $pprice);

 $s->bindColumn('productIMG', $pimg); 

 $numRows = $s->rowCount();

include_once('resultat_recherche.html.php');

exit();

  } catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo "Issue with your query";
  }  
}// FIN DE GET
```

### ?>

resultat_recherche.html.php

```
<div id="container">
<div class="searchcolumn">
<div class="mocassinsimg">

<ul>
  <?php foreach($row = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $key ):

      if ($pos++ % COLS==0 && !$firstRow) {

        echo "<ul></ul>";
      }

   ?>   
 <a href="<?php echo $key['productIMG'];?>">
  <li>
<img src="images/<?php echo $key['productIMG'];?>" alt="<?php echo $key['productNAME'];?>"  width="230" heigth="280"/>

<h4 class="nom"><?php echo $key['productNAME'];?></h4>

    <p class="desc"><?php echo $key['productDESC'];?></p>

    <p class="prix"><?php echo $key['productPRICE']. " ".$currency;?></p>
  </li></a>
<?php endforeach;?>
  </ul>
        </div>

    </div><!--end#content-->
```

product db looks something like that

```
productID    1
productNAME  bag
productIMG   bag.jpg
```

So how can I find the path of the images if a men-fashion product has been entered in the search bar or a women-fashion product.

The idea was like if a person hover a product of men fashion the url should look like:

`egoshop/men-fashion/tie.jpg...`  That is the reason i created a folder for men-fashion with the images files inside an images folder... and same for women-fashion as welle

Comment: are you saving that folder path in the database?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: Yes i am...the file path like..bag.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Could you give more code about the search function/structure ?

However, the best practice would be to have one folder with all he images named according to the id of the product (ex : 104.jpg) and you would retrieve them only by using the product's id + .jpg.

Comment: you don't necessarily have to use the products id either, you could have a column in the database called `file_name`, and another called `file_ext`, and as long as you know where the image is located, you can can build the file name based on those two columns.

Comment: @l3aronsansgland: i will post the search code..and the site structure then

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: Thanks for precious advice...things works good now just the way i expected.